# Positioning JPanels in a BorderLayout

Tags: java, swing

I have two `JPanels` added to a `Frame` with a `BorderLayout`. This is what i want:
[image]

This is what I have:
[image]

I cannot figure out how to position the buttons and `JPanels`...this is my code:

```
mainPanel=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
topPanel=new JPanel();
bottPanel=new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
bottPanel.add(importButton,BorderLayout.WEST);
bottPanel.add(convertButton,BorderLayout.EAST);

this.add(bottPanel,BorderLayout.SOUTH);
this.add(topPanel,BorderLayout.NORTH);
this.setVisible(true);
```

Comment: What if you add `topPanel` at `BorderLayout.CENTER` instead of `BorderLayout.NORTH` ?

Comment: Nothing changes

Comment: Why does your code have a statement for a "mainPanel". You never add anything to the panel. Based on your code the two buttons should be displayed at the left/right of the frame, but the top panel is empty to there is nothing to display so the buttons will be displayed at the top of the frame. Post a proper [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem. We can't guess what you are doing wrong based on incomplete code. We need to know the context of how the code is invoked.

Answer (score 0):

You should fill the main panel with somethin, otherwise it will display just the elements that you incuded avoiding in this case the BorderLayout.CENTER section.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/BorderLayout.html
http://www.wideskills.com/java-tutorial/java-borderlayout-class-example

Just play with it!

I used to play with the background color in order to see how it behaves when I was learning.

Comment: What do you mean with "fill the main panel with somethin"?

Comment: If there is nothing into BorderLayout.CENTER section, it will not be displayed (the entire section is avoided). Try adding a button or any other element.

Comment: But what if I want to use only this components?

Comment: If I were you I would put a main panel with BorderLayout. Then another panel with BorderLayout too, into the SOUTH section of the main panel.
And this secondary panel will have the buttons on EAST and WEST, and a empty JPanel in the CENTER.
Good luck!

Comment: In the secondary panel you can use other Layouts, like GridLayout... that is up to you

Comment: You need some more components, at least anonymous ones inserted.